# SSRS not displaying external image with parameter source in asp.net remote Report

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have asp.net application in framework 4.0. i have created one image folder in my project, images are added in that folder. and i have SSRS report deployed on same server.i am using external image source but images from the reports are not displayed. can anybody help to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS report is looking for Image folder which is available in virtual directory where SSRS reports have deployed or configured. Create Image Folder in that directory and put your images there.